# Replace form with another form on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have 2 forms. I want when button is clicked to show another form on first form position. So just to replace that form.

**Form 1**

```
<div id="right"> 
    <form id="contact" class="visible" action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <input name="fname" placeholder="Ime" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input name="lname" placeholder="Prezime" type="text" tabindex="2" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input name="tel" placeholder="Telefon" type="text" tabindex="2" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Pošalji</button>   
        </fieldset>         
    </form> 
</div>
```

**Form 2**

```
<div id="form2">
    <form id="contact2" action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <input name="fname" placeholder="Ime" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input name="lname" placeholder="Prezime" type="text" tabindex="2" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input name="tel" placeholder="Telefon" type="text" tabindex="2" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Pošalji</button>   
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $("#contact-submit").on("click", function() {
      $("#contact").removeClass("visible");
      $("#form2").addClass("visible");
    });
```

So for some reason this is not working. Please help me to solve this. I tried to set `opacity:0;` of first form but it doesn't work. And please let me know which libary is should use.

Here is my example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzKaPa

Comment: I'm assuming your form is actually being submitted which is resulting in your page reloading. You need to intercept the form submit.

Comment: I would point out that you shouldn't use opacity to hide and show things. It just visibly hides the element. The user can still react with the element. Such as they could click the invisible input and start typing. Then submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: So I looked at your pen and fixed it so it works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXjEQd

It looks like you'll need to do a couple of things, one of which you might have already: first, place your jquery in a ready function (and make sure you've linked a jquery version in your head tag)--

```
$(function(){ 
    // your code
});
```

Then, in your click handler, add a preventDefault():

```
$('#contact-submit').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of code
});
```

e.preventDefault() keeps your submit button from doing it's default action--submitting the form. This lets you perform other actions with the button. If you don't include this, the very first thing that will happen when your button is clicked is form submission, and you'll not get to any of the other code inside your click event.

This also assumes you have a .visible class defined in your css. If not, you'll need to add that as well, or instead of using addClass and removeClass, you'll need to change the display property on the form directly:

```
$('#contact').css('display','none');
$('#form2').css('display','block');
```

Comment: Good answer, I would just add why `preventDefault()` should be used +1

Comment: @Cruiser it helps me, thank you. But only problem is that inputs must be filled. In this example you can skipp them. So, first form must be filled, than show the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have defined the class `visible` somewhere else (and have set the CSS defaults for your forms to be hiddne, adding or removing it will have no effect.

Instead, I'd recommend you directly change the `display` property of the two:

```
$("#form2").css("display", "none"); // so it's initially invisible
$("#contact-submit").on("click", function() {
  $("#contact").css("display", "none");
  $("#form2").css("display", "");
});
```

This will directly alter the `style` attribute on each element, causing them to hide or show.  Using `css("display", "")` will remove the setting.

You might also look into the `hide` and `show` methods in jQuery as they can do the same thing, only with a nice animation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have specific CSS that applies to elements with or without the class 'visible', removing and adding that class to the elements will do nothing.

You may want to try

```
$("#contact-submit").on("click", function() {
  $("#contact").toggle();
  $("#form2").toggle();
});
```

to toggle form visibility, and you can initially apply visibility on the forms using CSS or built-in jQuery classes.